# Web API Post Body Properties null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm posting over a message from an Angular application and every time the post body is always coming into the function as null. A console log in the Angular application directly before the post request confirmed that the object did contain information, it seems to get lost somewhere along the way through.

```
public class SentMessage
{
    public string MessageFrom { get; set; }
    public string MessageTo { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

// Post a new message
[Route("Conversation/AddTo")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult AddToConversation(SentMessage message)
{
    if (message is null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok("Message Sent");
}
```

So far I've tried with and without [FromBody] on the method property as suggested in other posts, but past that I'm not sure what's going wrong.

........

Comment: Put `[FromBody]` on the method argument, as you've said, and make sure you're POSTing with the `Content-Type` of `application/json`.

Comment: Perfect Thanks - if you want to pop that in I'll mark it as an answer for you if you like?

Comment: Thanks very much. Glad it worked for you. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `[FromBody]` on the method argument, as you've said, and make sure you're POSTing with the `Content-Type` of `application/json`.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify the code

```
public IHttpActionResult AddToConversation([FromBody]SentMessage message)
{
    if (message is null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok("Message Sent");
}
```